# Unable to access Images inside a War file

Tags: java, image, spring, spring-mvc, war

I have a war file that I have deployed which contains an images folder in the `WEB-APP` directory. I tried accessing the images stored in the folder using
"localhost:8080/testapp/images/image1.jpg" but I am getting a 404 response. Can someone please help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more details or some code? If you are using Windows, you can execute `tree /a /f` on the deployed directory.

Comment: @PaulVargas Assuming it's been exploded.

Comment: Please provide details regarding where precisely the images are located in the war's file hierarchy.

Comment: @DaveNewton You are right! Anything can happen.

Comment: I need to allow an application on another machine to access these images. Hence I have stored them in the war file and deployed it to the server. I am on Mac OS.

Comment: The structure of my project is: testapp-src->main->web-app -> WEB-INF -> images.

Comment: In the war file the structure is .war -> WEB-INF -> images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *images* directory needs to be a sibling of *WEB-INF*, not a child of it.  Try this:

```
your-war-file.war
  |-images/
  |   |-image1.jpg
  |   |-image2.jpg
  |   `-image3.jpg
  |-WEB-INF/
  |   |-classes/
  |   |-lib/
  |   `-web.xml
  |-index.html
  `-404.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your folder 'images' in the base directory for this web app (on the same level as 'META-INF' and 'WEB-INF' catalogs), the path seems correct. Maybe check that you haven't put 'images' folder inside 'WEB-INF' where it is not accessible? If that doesn't work, try accessing some other file inside your web app to check that it was deployed on server.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your help! I changed my images folder to be in the same base directory as META-INF and WEB-INF and re-deployed the war file but I am still getting the same error.. Could you please help me with it?

Comment: okay i guess there can be any reason now. maybe you can check that: 1. your web server starts (look at the script output and/or log files); 2. make sure the web app is deployed (in 'webapps' or similarly named catalog in your web server by default the war file should get exploded, that is unzipped into regular folder) 3. try accessing some other static content from your web app - maybe you have some javascript or css file -> if nothing gets served then must be sth with paths/port/server/webapp 4. you can also look at the server start log to make sure the port is correct etc...

Comment: I got it working by moving the folder to the base directory. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Clients may not directly access artifacts under WEB-INF.

Put them in a location directly accessible if you're not streaming them from an app endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

how to read from path ?
use ("."+File.seperator+"some else") path of File for current path into your code or html file

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail? Or provide an example? Thanks in advance.